# How can we Migrate tableau analysis to Quick Sight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, tableau-desktop

I imported one csv file inside the tableau desktop and added the calculated fields and analyze the same data with different visual types, now my requirement is how can i migrate tableau analysis inside the Quick sight with out any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, you're probably looking at a manual solution where you import your CSV file into QuickSight and re-create your calculated fields and other analysis. I've worked with both applications and have yet to find a streamlined migration path.

You could investigate the Tableau APIs and see if you can get some JSON that might work with QuickSight, but that seems a lot of effort for what sounds like a proof-of-concept type situation.